# Bruhat order and RSK

Tags: combinatorics, symmetric-groups

The [RS(K) correspondence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson-Schensted_algorithm) is a bijection between elements of the symmetric group $S_n$ and pairs of standard tableaux of the same shape.  The symmetric group is partially ordered by the Bruhat order, so this bijection induces a partial ordering "$\leq$"on the set of pairs of standard tableaux.  Is a natural "tableaux-theoretic" description of this ordering on pairs of tableaux known?  That is, can we give a condition for $(S,T)\leq (S',T')$ more natural than "apply RSK in reverse and see if the second permutation dominates the first in the Bruhat order"?

Comment: Now crossposted at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/102232/bruhat-order-and-the-robinson-schensted-correspondence